# How to return a database connection from a function?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I need to modify some legacy code that was written in classic ASP (VBscript).

I have a line that sets a database connection like this:

```
set m_conn=OpenConn()
```

I believe that the `OpenConn()` function is in a DLL somewhere. This is bad news because we can't locate the source for that dll. So, I've been working on a replacement for that function. This is what i have so far:

```
function OpenConn()

dim conn
set conn = server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
conn.open "XXXXconnection-stringXXXXX"  
OpenConn = conn

end function
```

When I try to run the original line `set m_conn=OpenConn()` (line 50) I get an ASP error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 

Object required: '[string: "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"]' 

/path/to/include.asp, line 50
```

I'm not too clear on how this syntax is supposed to work. Usually, I work in C#, but when I need to do things like this in ASP I'd use syntax like this:

```
set conn = server.createobject("adodb.conection")
conn.activeconnection = "connectionstring"
conn.execute "sql"
set conn = nothing
```

Anyway, I'm looking for the correct syntax for `OpenConn()` so that `set m_conn=OpenConn()` will work correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a little more poking around, I figured it out.

The function definition should have been:

```
function OpenConn() 

    dim conn 
    set conn = server.CreateObject("adodb.connection") 
    conn.open "XXXXconnection-stringXXXXX"   

    set OpenConn = conn  ' change - added "set"

end function
```